# Create / add up array with switch statements

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, switch-statement

For readability and perfomance reasons, I'd like to build up an array with a switch statement instead of `if-statements`.

Consider the following if-statement:

```
$size = 2;
$array = array();
if($size >= 1) { array_push($array,'one','foo'); }
if($size >= 2) { array_push($array,'two','bar','barista'); }
if($size >= 3) { array_push($array,'three','zoo','fool','cool','moo'); }
```

It basically counts up from `1` to `$size`, it might be more readable and most likely a lot faster with a switch-statment...**but how do you construct that ??**

```
$step = 2;
$array = array();
switch($step)
{
    case ($step>1): array_push($array,'one','foo');
    case ($step>2): array_push($array,'two','bar','barista');
    case ($step>3): array_push($array,'three','zoo','fool','cool','moo');
}
```

I tried leaving out the `break`, which didn't work - as the manual says:

> In a switch statement, the condition is evaluated only once[...].
>   PHP continues to execute the statements until the end of the switch
>   block, or the first time it sees a break statement.

Anyway, anyone got an idea how to build up such an array with a `switch`-statement ??

Comment: with the code you wrote, in every case you'll enter in the first if statement, because if you have a size=2 or 3 or more, the first if will be true.
Why don't you do something more simple like: $array[] = $size; instead of those if?

Comment: @Marco Pace The content of the array is just an example, actually I have other values in it...gonna change my example to make it more clear...

Comment: $size = 3+ will match all conditions. $size = 2 will match conditions 1 and 2. $size = 1 will match condition 1 only and $size = 0 will not match any condition. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely what you want can be achieved much more easily using

```
$array=range(1,$size);
```

Based on further coments and subsequent edits, something like:

```
$baseArray = $array(array('one'),
                    array('two','twoA'),
                    array('three','threeA','threeB'),
                    array(),
                    array('five'),
                   );
$step=2;
$array = array_slice($baseArray,0,$step);
```

and then flatten $array

Comment: Clarified my desired outcome of the array a bit more, see the comment section of my question! I want to have some dynamic values, not numbers in the array. Sorry for confusion

Comment: I got some problems to express myself today :D I have some more variables, not just 1 each case - sometimes 1, sometimes 3. Gonna re-edit again to clarify further.

Comment: **now** it's what I want, great job and it's not even any conditional statement or a loop so I just assume it's faster - tell me if I'm wrong! Thanks a lot for that and your patience!

Comment: You'll need a loop to flatten the array to a straight 1-D array, but there's a lot of examples of this given on http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php (including using efficient functions like array_walk_recursive() as the looping function.... so it should be a lot more efficient than ifs or cases

Answer (score 1):

Well, a switch statement would look like:

edit: the above doesn't work - let me take a look.

but in this example, you could just do:

```
$size = 2;
$array = range(1, $size); // Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
```

Comment: In your switch statement, I won't add up an array, because in case of `$size = 2` it will stop (`break`) after the first statement! For the second, please see my reply on the comments of my question

Answer (score 1):

```
$valuesIWant = array(1=>'one','two','three','four');
$array = array();
for ($i = $step - 1; $i > 0; $i--) $array[] = $valuesIWant[$i];
$array = array_reverse($array);
```

So if `$step` is 2, you get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
)
```

...and if it is 4, you get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
)
```

Comment: I see what you are doing and the idea is good (+1), although it doesn't fit perfectly to my case as I'm having a varying number of variables each case. Mark Baker perfected the idea simultaniously.